# Learning VB and need to fill a variable a buttons .text thats dependent on the button pushed

Tags: vb.net

My goal is to have the user able to push any button and the .text of the button to be passed into a a text box. the below is a very simplified version of what i want to achieve... i know i can have each button in its own sub however doing this will create hundreds of lines of code while if what i wish to do works, it will only be a few lines...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuF5n.png

```
Sub Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click
TextBox1.Text = (TextBox1.Text + ??? )
End Sub
```

so what would i replace the ??? with to represent the .text of the button the user pushes?

(This is using VB in Visual Studios 2013)

Thank you in advance ^.^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sender` parameter is the sender of the event. You’ll probably need to cast it before doing anything useful:

```
Dim button As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
```

Then you can use it:

```
TextBox1.Text &= button.Text
```

Comment: You actually don't need to cast it here; just sender.name.tostring would be just fine...

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR: If you have `Option Strict Off`, which is a bad idea. Type-safety is nice.